# What do MySQL aborted connections visible in phpMyAdmin mean?

Tags: mysql

I host my websites on a server that has some problems with MySQL. Looking at PHPMyAdmin *statistics* tab, I see these stats:

[PHPMyAdmin stats http://www.slagalica.tv/henet.mysql.png](http://www.slagalica.tv/henet.mysql.png)

It shows that 99.68% connections have beed aborted. I googled a little bit about it, but I can't figure out what it really means. What is the reason for this and how can it be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/communication-errors.html

An aborted connection is one that:

- didn't call mysql_close
- timed out
- had some real error

I'm guessing from the very high rate that you're creating connections to the database but not closing them when you're finished with them.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know whether PHPMyAdmin reports Aborted Connections only or Aborted Clients (which are listed on the page you wrote about) as well?

Answer (score 1):

The most common reason for an aborted connection is bad coding. Programs open the connection but don't close it when they're done. Just sloppy programming.